# How to auto-archive mails after sent?

Tags: mail.app, email, mail-rules

Is it possible to auto-archive mails, after sending - or adding a separate "Send and archive" button?

I use the Inbox Zero approach, so now I need to manually archive conversations that have ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many functions that are available in the Mail.app plugin [Mailhub](http://dervishsoftware.com).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of tools that help you archive your mails automatically.
https://www.macupdate.com/apps/358562/mail-archiving

I use Mail Backup X

Comment: Not a huge fan of MacUpdate or paying $79 for a very limited piece of software. What other options are there?

Comment: there could be many, but I can only suggest the one I have had used. Suggest me, if any better alternative is available that manages multiple mail accounts, backs them up, at different locations at a time.